# python gspread oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, gspread

According to the following post [#244](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/224) to authenticate the credential we can define GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to directly authenticate.

Here is what I did in my code.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
credentials.create_scoped(['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'])
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open("hello").sheet1
```

But when I run this it raises an oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with server time (run "date" command).  I would suggest setting up NTP on your server to have it update time automatically.

CentOS NTP
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-ntp-to-synchronize-server-clock/

Ubuntu NTP
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: Hi @Robert, I think this is not a time issue.  When I ran the date command, nothing is wrong. Will above code work in your system?

Comment: Yes.  I updated NTP on my server and updated the time.  It fixed this specific issue.

Comment: I have figured out the problem here. I first got SpreadsheetNotFound exception, then I added my own email to the client_email entry in my credential file, which caused this problem. Instead I should shared my spread sheet with the client email address listed in the credential file.

Comment: Good to know you figured it out